# How can I efficiently mimic a foreign key constraint when the field it references is autoincrementing?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship, auto-increment

I'm attempting to create a database application for a bookstore.

In the spec:
"After registration, a user can order one or more books. The total amount of the order should be reported to him/her. A user may order multiple copies of a book, one or more times."

The total amount bit doesn't seem that bad.

Here are the two relevant tables:

Order(**orderID**: INT(11), loginName: VARCHAR(45), date: DATETIME)

BooksOrdered(**orderID**: INT(11), **ISBN**: VARCHAR(45), count: INT(11))

The bolded items are the PKs.

Now, here's the deal: Our database doesn't allow FKs for performance issues, so I'm supposed to mimic them in the application layer. BooksOrdered.orderID is really a FK, just not stated as much. Additionally, Order.orderID is autoincrementing.

I'm trying to figure out how to make sure the orderID's match up (mimic the foreign key constraint) when inserting new orders.

Basically, I don't understand how I can efficiently insert an order given an ArrayList (BookOrder will simply hold an ISBN and a count).

One solution I've thought of is:

Every time I want to add a row into BooksOrdered, simply grab the largest orderID from Order. This seems inefficient, and I think there might be other issues with it (concurrent access/insertions?).

Therefore I ask you, how should I go about mimicking this autoincrementing FK? Or would you suggest I restructure my tables?

Or is there a way I can magically grab the last orderID I insert into Order... say in the process of inserting?

EDIT:

Alright, so I have the following incomplete function:

```
public int orderBooks(String loginName, ArrayList<BookOrder> bookOrders) throws Exception{

    int id = -1;
    //Working on the date situation
    java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
    Timestamp sqlDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(today.getTime());

    Connector con=null;
    String query = "INSERT INTO Order (loginName, date) " +
            " VALUES ('"+loginName+"', "+sqlDate+")";
    ResultSet rs; 


    try{
        con= new Connector();
        con.stmt.executeUpdate(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        rs = con.stmt.getGeneratedKeys();
        if (rs.next()) {
            id = rs.getInt(1);
        } else {
            throw(new Exception()); // mmm...
            // throw an exception from here
        }
        con.stmt.close();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to execute query:"+query+"\n");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        throw(e);
    }
    finally
     {
         if (con != null)
         {
             try
             {
                 con.closeConnection();
             }
             catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */ }
         }
     }




    return id;
}
```

Now, where should I put id = stmt.executeUpdate(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);? Did I put it in the right spot? (continues to work on building a testable prototype)

Comment: *Our database doesn't allow FKs for performance issues."*

You mean your database/application designer does not allow Foreign Keys. DBMS are built to use Foreign Keys and one reason is performance issues, which can benefit from FKs - despite the opposite opinion by some..".

Comment: @Silver: Your database designer needs training..He should stop living in fantacy and should start exploring Why microsoft/Oracle are doing this foolish mistake giving foreign key and other constraints in database when performance gets degrade. http://goo.gl/HRkj1 http://goo.gl/xl5Ua there are so many articles that your designer must google it once..

Comment: Thank you, I will let him know. I wish I could use FKs... would make things much easier

Comment: Read this: [Do Foreign Key Constraints Help Performance?](http://www.scarydba.com/2010/11/22/do-foreign-key-constraints-help-performance/) and pass it through...

Comment: @ypercube: there is a similar example for Oracle as well: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-may/o39asktom-096149.html

Comment: "How can I efficiently mimic a foreign key" -- with a very carefully coded trigger... but the performance will be much worse! Sure, the business layer should be coded to refrain from writing bad data but the database must be (or have direct access to) the trusted source of constraints (the 'machine understood' business rules).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which language are you using? It will likely have a function to retrieve the last autoincremented value from your current database handle. In PHP, for example, you would use `mysql_insert_id()` ([doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)). In Perl DBI you can use `last_insert_id()`. ([DBI Doc](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.618/DBI.pm#last_insert_id))

For have you want to set the flag in executeUpdate:

```
id = stmt.executeUpdate(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

There's also the `stmt.getGeneratedKeys()` function. [See the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29). The executeUpdate entry is right below getGeneratedKeys.

Comment: I'm using Java, wait, just found something:
"select LAST_INSERT_ID()"
Like that? Kinda?
Also, would that be good with concurrent access by many users?

Comment: So you're using executeUpdate? Try this: `numero = stmt.executeUpdate(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);` It's more portable and more efficient that doing the second call to mysql's last_insert_id(), which I *think* can have some other issues iirc.

Comment: Yeah I'm using executeUpdate. Alright, cool thanks I'll give it a go!

Comment: Cool. I added the java info to the answer above. :)

Comment: Alright, so I edited my original post, what do you think about where I placed the id = stmt.executeUpdate(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);? (still working on it so I can test it myself, I'll put an update here when I have something working)

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct. From reading over the docs a few times it looks like after the statement is executed you need to call the `getGeneratedKeys()` function and the RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS boolean just makes them available for that function. So if you have issues I'd try that.